# How can cold air inflow in high tropospheric layers create a depression?

Tags: ppl, meteorology

I’m studying meteorology for PPL and after learning the big differences between cyclones and anticyclones, I came across a question that flipped all my knowledge on its head:

> What pressure pattern may result from cold-air inflow in high
> tropospheric layers?
>
> A: Formation of a low in the upper troposphere

I’ve spent hours on all facets of this question and I still don’t understand how cold air inflow can create a low in the upper tropospheric layers.

Apparently this cold air inflow at high tropospheric layers triggers a through, which would be a catalyst for ts and cb.

But at the same time it doesn’t make it clear how cold air can create a low, cyclone, which is actually characterized by rising warm air that cools.

There is a variation of this q that talks about `what weather conditions should be expected in an upper level through` and it suggests that‘s `development of showers and thunderstorms`.

But I thought throughs in lows happen at ground level, because air rises in lows.

Comment: These days when we can just check the near-term forecasts on the internet, it seems odd to have that kind of detailed theoretical meteorological question on the PPL exam!

Comment: I agree, and what’s worse is many questions only make more sense once you tap into ATPL resources. 
It’s either books need updating or questions need to be less ambiguous.

Comment: Best book on aviation weather theory, bar none, is the manual published for Royal Canadian Air Force pilot training. It's a fundamental part of the ATPL knowledge base. Extremely well written. https://publications.gc.ca/site/eng/9.652598/publication.html#:~:text=The%20Royal%20Canadian%20Air%20Force,taught%20in%20a%20classroom%20setting.